# Current consumption estimation for IC

Tags: datasheet

I am interested in theoretically calculating the current consumption for a design I am currently working on. My final goal is the design of the proper power management circuit. I am a bit confused on which current values I should pick from every datasheet in order to approach a descent and "realistic" calculation. For example, I plan to integrate a [TXS0108E](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0108e.pdf) IC. At page 6, electrical characteristics table, what is each current reported? I have done some search and found that I_I and I_OZ are leakage currents, right? But then the test conditions for the I_CCA and I_CCB include zero I_O. Should I include only dynamic values for my estimation or leakage ones as well? Which ones are dynamic and which are leakage?

Comment: Those look like all static. But you can't estimate power consumption based on the device alone. The signal states on either side will make a big difference, as will any signal that has any appreciable frequency.

Comment: Thanks, Trevor. I am trying to find out which voltage rails are essential on board and which components should be supplied by each rail. So, how should I continue with the power management circuit if I can find or calculate only the static currents of the devices in their datasheets?

Comment: That's a big question. The extents of the math, if you were to attempt to do it completely, get to be extreme depending on the complexity of your entire system. In the end it is usual to result to ball park figures for each device based on the whatever they are driving plus their quiescent current. But in digital systems, there is no real substitute for building it and measuring the consumption in various states remembering to add in a little for part variance trusting in your initial design decisions and part selections to minimize current.